# Action Script ScoreBoard

Tags: actionscript-3, helper

Hallo I'm the beginner,
 I have here my AS3 code.

```
package  
{
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Artur
     */
    public class Scoreboard extends TextField
    {
        public var score:int;
        public function Scoreboard() 
        {
            score = 0;
            var txtf:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
            txtf.color = 0xFFCC33;
            txtf.size = 25;
            txtf.font = "verdana";
            txtf.bold = true;
            this.defaultTextFormat = txtf;
            this.text = "Score : 0"
            this.width = 300;
            this.x = 530;
        }
        public function updateScore(_score:int):void 
        {
            score += _score;
            this.text = "Score: " + score;
        }

    }

}
```

I would Like to change color of the TextFormat, if score is bigger then 100 it will change color to green
and if it's lower then 0 to red.

I have this code.

```
    if (score>100){
        txtf.color = 0xFFCC33;

} else if (score>50){
        txtf.color = 0xFFCC33;


}
```

I don't know how to implement it into the first code.
Can somebody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: well, think about it. _when_ would you check for the current score to see how high it is?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I need to use addEventListener to check it. I'm programming in AC3 at school 2 weeks long now, in free time ass well but I don't know much about that.

Comment: Actually, the solution is much simpler. You should check the score when you change the score. And the only part in your code where you change the score is in the function `updateScore(int)`. Just as Akmozo pointed out in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
...

public function updateScore(_score:int):void {

    score += _score

    if (score > 100){

        txtf.color = 0x00FF00    // green

    } else if (score < 0){

        txtf.color = 0xFF0000    // red

    }   
    this.setTextFormat(txtf)
    this.text = "Score: " + score

}

...
```

Note that is just to improve your code, I dont know when and where you call `updateScore`.

EDIT

Declaring `txtf`

```
...

private var txtf:TextFormat

public function Scoreboard() {

    ...        

    txtf = new TextFormat()

    ....

}

...
```

Comment: you should declare `txtf` outside the constructor of your class.

Comment: Thank you, Im getting error : C(33): col: 9 Error: Access of undefined property txtf.
        txtf.color = 0x00FF00    // green
        ^
C:\): col: 9 Error: Access of undefined property txtf.
        txtf.color = 0xFF0000    // red
        ^
(40): col: 24 Error: Access of undefined property txtf.
    this.setTextFormat(txtf)
                       ^
Build halted with errors (fcsh).

Comment: Ehh i dont get it at all anymore.

Comment: Do you mean that you got what you want ?